# markerclusterer test file not working

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I hesitate to post this item--I must be making a simple mistake.

I copied the example code for MarkerClusterer and linked to the data source file and markerclusterer source file on http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer, but when I run the test on localhost, it throws an error that "Error: ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined".

I also tried copying the json file and the js file to my local server, but got the same error.

Here is my code. Can anyone tell me what silly mistake I'm making, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MarkerClusterer v3 Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      #map-container {
        padding: 6px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
        width: 600px;
      }

      #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }

    </style>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/data.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js ';
      if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
        script += '_compiled';
      }
      script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
      document.write(script);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
              dataPhoto.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>A simple example of MarkerClusterer (100 markers)</h3>
    <p>
      <a href="">Compiled</a> |
      <a href="">Standard</a> version of the script.
    </p>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js ';
      if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
        script += '_compiled';
      }
      script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
      document.write(script);
    </script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

(it is usually safer to copy the file to your local server and reference it there, unless it is a [google hosted library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/))

[Working example of MarkerClusterer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html)